# How to find the URL of a RESTful API inside of said API

Tags: java, url, rest

Say I have this endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/{product}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getProduct(
        @PathParam("product") final String product) {
    return createSignature(<<PLACE COMPLETE URL HERE>>);
}
```

How can I know the complete URL that is being called from inside the endpoint in order to maybe create a signature based on that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. 
Generally you can add special parameter to method or a field to your resource class. Special parameter is recognized by type (HttpServletRequest or UriInfo) and should be marked using annotaiton `@Context`.

@StormBringerX already mentioned that the information may be passed using method parameter (+1). I personally prefer to add this as a field of your class because I think this is clearer  and allows creating methods that accept only application level parameters.

Comment: True; also UriInfo is more appropriate for the OPs problem as you get a whole bunch of additional stuff with HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @StormBringerX thanks for the suggestion, but I rather have the endpoints as clean as possible.

Comment: This page presents both approaches. Thanks again! [Obtaining information about URIs using UriInfo objects](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxrs_contextobjects_uri.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the original request by adding `@Context HttpServletRequest request` as a parameter to your method. You can then access anything you want to do with the request.